# О вражении "обреченный на успех"

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, почему слово "обреченный" употребляется в негативном значении, но при этом есть выражение "обреченный на успех"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не думаю, что это оксюморон, но что выразительное средство - точно. Скорее всего, это контаминация фразеологизмов ОБРЕЧЬ НА ПРОВАЛ,ПОРАЖЕНИЕ и НАДЕЖДА НА УСПЕХ  или нарушение лексической сочетаемости как выразительное средство.От слова "обречь, обречённый" взято значение бесспорности, несомненности, от слова "успех" - положительные эмоции, положительная оценка события(обречённый на победу - то же самое). 
Из этой же серии :вместо "потерпеть неудачу" -  "увенчаться провалом","причинить удовольствие" и "насаждать демократию".

Answer (score 2):

**"Обреченный на успех"** - выражение, означающее, что успех ждёт несомненный, бесспорный, независимо от обстоятельств. Произносится с оттенком иронии, подчёркивающей эту несомненность. Это своего рода оксюморон, выразительное средство.
**Обречь** - предназначить к какой-л. неизбежной участи (обычно тяжёлой). О. на вечное одиночество.
dic.academic.ru › Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
**Успех**. М. 1. Удача в каком-либо деле, удачное достижение поставленной цели. отт. Удача в военной операции; победа. 2. Признание такой удачи со стороны окружающих, общественное одобрение чего-либо или чьих-либо достижений. 
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ефремовой

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, обреченный не всегда означало только на что-то негативное. 
Так что то, что сейчас воспринимается как контаминация на самом деле раньше вполне могло быть вполне нормальным оборотом. Не знаю, правда, сколь древнее это выражение, могло ли оно возникнуть в те времена, когда "обреченный на победу" или "обреченный на жизнь" бытовали как вполне обычные сочетания.

Comment: Ну да, Вы правы.Это причастие восходит к общеславянскому rektin имеет тот же корень, что и существительное речь. Буквально – "приговорить словами к чему-то".Но потом появилось отглаг. прилагательное от церковного глагола обрещи,( церк.) посвящать, предназначать, определять, жертвовать. Значение "жертвовать" породило смысл "смерть", приблизило к слову "рок".Так что старое причастие вполне допускает смысл "создать принудительные условия чего-либо", а прилагательное "обречённый"- пожертвованный року, смерти. Но это старое значение, видимо, возвратилось.

Comment: >Это причастие восходит к общеславянскому rektin    
  
Наверное **rekti**? Откуда n в "общеславянском" глаголе?

Answer (score 1):

Кто-нибудь обратил внимание на то, как в заголовке написано слово "выражение"? 
Нет нужды рассматривать это выражение, т.к. оно не имеет смысла и рождено в период начала предпринимательства в постсоветской России. "Мы обречены на успех!" - так начинающие бизнесмены успокаивали себя и своих сотрудников, когда у них на душе было очень неспокойно. Они не зря беспокоились. Бизнес - очень рискованное занятие. Почти все обречённые на успех пополнили ряды безработных и простых менеджеров.